# Unity LoadLevel not releasing last level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are 3 scenes in my game,

```
1st - Menu
2nd - Game level
3rd - Leaderboard
```

the menu scene and the others have different resolutions and what happens when I load the game level with:

```
Application.LoadLevel("levelName");
```

from the menu I can still see it (the menu scene) because its resolution is bigger.
I guess I am missing a concept here and I will have to learn a bit more about scene design so any good tutorial or document will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by the scenes are different resolutions?

Comment: do you have `DontDestroyOnLoad(...)` in any of your scripts? if so which/where/how etc. That function should be the only way something (and all it's children) survives a `LoadLevel` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are not using `Application.LoadLevelAdditive()`, calling `DontDestroyOnLoad()`, or using `static` then nothing from a previous scene will survive.